# stopping addCh() from overwriting frollowing chars (ncurses, c)

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I working on a basic ncurses program and ran across this issue.

I am trying to call addch() without overwritten the following characters.

Basically, I want to be able to type out something like

"elp!"

Use the left cursor to move to the first position, and then type h in front of the current text to get

"help!"

Right now that behavior would result in

"hlp"

With the h overwriting the first character.

My code showing this issue:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
initscr();
cbreak();
noecho();
intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
clear();

short currentCh;
int x, y;

while (currentCh = getch()) {
  bool modeChange = false;
  getyx(stdscr, y, x);

  if (currentCh == KEY_LEFT) {
    if (x != 0)
      move(y, x - 1);
  } else {
    addch(currentCh);
  }
}
```

My best idea so far seems to be to save all characters typed in a string, then modify that string with the correct new characters, then clear the screen and call addstr() each time a char is typed (In other words you are printing the contents of a string, instead of character by character).

This requires you to clear the screen after each ch, and rewriting everything.

This is obviously janky, and not ideal, so I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: `My best idea so far seems to be to save all characters typed in a string, then modify that string with the correct new characters, then clear the screen and call addstr() each time a char is typed` Yes, and this is called double buffering and will ease development. `This requires you to clear` No, you can keep what is on the screen in another buffer, and update only changes between buffer that keeps what is on the screen and buffer with new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `addch` for that special case, you can ***insert*** a character using [`insch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_insch.3x.html):

> These routines insert the character ch before the character  under  the
> cursor.   All characters to the right of the cursor are moved one space
> to the right, with the possibility of the rightmost  character  on  the
> line  being  lost.   The insertion operation does not change the cursor
> position.

For instance, you could decide to use that when the current cell contains something other than a blank.  You can read that character using [`inch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) (similar spelling, different meaning):

> These routines return the character, of type  **`chtype`**,  at  the  current
> position  in  the  named  window.   If  any attributes are set for that
> position, their values are OR'ed into the  value  returned.   Constants
> defined  in <curses.h> can be used with the & (logical AND) operator to
> extract the character or attributes alone.

(as noted in the manual page, ***AND*** the return value with `A_CHARTEXT` to get just the *character*).